# Atualizar JEditorPane conforme retorno de dados de uma função - JAVA

Tags: java, swing

Basicamente, a situação é a seguinte, tenho uma aplicação em Java que se comunica com uma API para atualizar um banco de dados. O problema que enfrento é o seguinte, estou fazendo o processo da seguinte forma:

**Classe da Aplicação**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        int idTipo=cmbTipos.getSelectedIndex()+1; 
        if(idTipo!=-1)//verifica se algum item foi selecionado
        {
            ApiFipe.GetsMarcas client = new ApiFipe.GetsMarcas();
            jedpAtualizados.setContentType("text/html");//define que o tipo de conteúdo do JEditorPane será text/html
            jedpAtualizados.setText(client.Get(idTipo));// aqui defino que o conteúdo será o que retornar da função que recebe os dados da api, e conforme os salva no banco de dados, concatena os dados que foram salvos em uma String e retorna essa String.
            cmbTipos.setSelectedIndex(-1);//reseta o combobox
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Categoria atualizada com sucesso!");//avisa que a operação foi realizada com sucesso
        }
```

**Classe GetsMarcas**

```
private String get(int idTipo)
{
    String retorno="";
    //recebe dados de uma api
    while(dadosdaapi.next()){
       //salva esses dados em um banco de dados
       retorno+=Integer.toString(objdedados.getCodigo());
   }
   return retorno;
}
```

Dessa forma, a aplicação fica "travada" até que todos os dados da api sejam salvos e a função retorne, o que eu gostaria de fazer é apresentar o código de cada item que foi salvo assim que isto ocorresse, desta forma atualizando o usuário sobre o progresso da atualização.

Comment: Essa api fornece os dados de forma individual? ou traz todas as marcas de uma vez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neto estou atualizando novamente a resposta porque realmente fica difícil entender onde está seu problema.

`resposta antiga`

> o `jop` `(JOptionPane)` não é uma boa caso queira que apareca uma tela
>   na cara do usuário informando que tal operação foi concluida, ainda
>   mais se for dentro de um laço while. Imagina se forem 50 repetições e
>   ele ter que abrir 50 caixas `jop` e o usuário ter que clicar 50 vezes
>   no botão ok, já que a caixa de dialogo não se fecha sozinha.
>
> o ideal (na minha opinião claro) seria ter uma label que informa o que
>   está acontecendo no momento e essa label ir mudando, para isso é
>   necessário que o bloco que faça a mudança dessa label esteja em uma
>   Thread para a aplicação em si não ficar travada até a conclusão. Ou
>   uma progressbar.. Enfim, vai do seu modo de implementar.

Segue exemplos ou tentativas dele de explicar como poderia atualizar informações em tempo real em que elas ocorrem:

- Considerações 1:

  Esse `jButton1ActionPerformed()` está sendo pressionado logo após o usuário selecionar algum tipo no combobox, então presumo que o `jedpAtualizados` vai ser preenchido com uma informação recebida do `client.get(idTipio)` e após isso o combobox vai voltar ao index -1 e logo no fim uma mensagem de conclusão.
- Considerações 2:

  Se aqui está o problema, se esse `get` é o que você quer fazer uma atualização em tempo real, vão algumas outras considerações:
  Esse `get(idTipo)` está sendo chamado uma única vez. Logo ele vai executar uma vez só e vai retornar uma `String` pelo que tudo indica. Essa `String` não sabemos se é grande ou pequena. Se será rapido o retorno ou não. Para que esse `jedAtualizados` seja realmente preenchido conforme o laço while do método `client.get(idTipo)`, então esse `jedAtualizados` tem que ser preenchido lá. Para isso é importante que o `jedAtualizados` seja static para poder ser acessado em outro local **OU** que você passe o jed como parametro no get do client.

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int idTipo = cmbTipos.getSelectedIndex() + 1; //obtem um id
        if (idTipo != -1)//verifica se algum item foi selecionado
        {
            ApiFipe.GetsMarcas client = new ApiFipe.GetsMarcas(); //instancia um client

            /* Leia considerações 1 */
            /* Leia Considerações 2*/
            jedpAtualizados.setContentType("text/html");

            /*linha removida*/
            //jedpAtualizados.setText(client.Get(idTipo));

            /*Linhas adicionadas para não deixar o JFrame atual ficar travado*/
            new Thread(() -> {
                //get corrigido para minusculo
                client.get(idTipo,jedpAtualizados); //Nesse contexto o próprio get já esta utilizando o jed para concatenar
                cmbTipos.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Categoria atualizada com sucesso!");
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

- Considerações 3:

Já na função `client.get(idTipo)` temos uma string vazia que vai receber a resposta da API. Dentro do laço while, temos como concatenação apenas numeros. Imagino eu que o retorno dessa string seria algo como *123248579875321* (só exemplo)... Enfim apenas números. Se é essa informação que quer que apareça no `jedAtualizados` então basta que dentro desse while você adicione esses valores ao `jedAtualizados`.

```java
private void get(int idTipo, JEditorPane jedpAtualizados) {
        /* leia considerações 3 */
        //recebe dados de uma api na variavel 'dadosdaapi'
        while (dadosdaapi.next()) {
            //salva esses dados em um banco de dados
            //aqui deve existir a criação desse objeto 'objdedados'

            /*Concatena as informações no jed*/
            jedpAtualizados.setText(jedpAtualizados.getText() + Integer.toString(objdedados.getCodigo());
        }
    }
```

- Considerações finais:

**Não vejo reais vantagens em fazer isso, só quis ilustrar** que **o uso de Threads** permite a edição de componentes sem deixar o `JFrame` atual travado.
Não há vantagens já que o retorno da API esta vindo toda em uma única requisição, ou seja, a demora em si está na requisição. O laço `while` vai percorrer informações já existentes e vai ser completado muito rápido, ou seja, vai preencher o `jepAtualizados` muito rápido, de forma a quase não se ver diferença nenhuma.